# Find and remove quotation indicators in Wikipedia text using regular expression

Tags: regex

During my text editing, I face a lot of quotation indicators, and I'm sure there is way to make my life simple and faster in handling these.

For instance, I only want to remove indicators such as `[1]`, `[2]`, `[3]`. Is there ways to do using regular expression?

Here's an example text that I'm working with:

> Blaise Pascal designed and constructed the first working mechanical calculator, Pascal's calculator, in 1642.[2] In 1673, Gottfried Leibniz demonstrated a digital mechanical calculator, called the Stepped Reckoner.[3] He may be considered the first computer scientist and information theorist, for, among other reasons, documenting the binary number system. In 1820, Thomas de Colmar launched the mechanical calculator industry[note 1] when he released his simplified arithmometer, which was the first calculating machine strong enough and reliable enough to be used daily in an office environment. Charles Babbage started the design of the first automatic mechanical calculator, his Difference Engine, in 1822, which eventually gave him the idea of the first programmable mechanical calculator, his Analytical Engine.[4] He started developing this machine in 1834 and "in less than two years he had sketched out many of the salient features of the modern computer".[5]

Comment: Yes, there is a way of doing this with regular expressions. Why are you copying and pasting so much of wikipedia that this is a problem?

Comment: And why are you parsing the rendered text instead of the page source? It won't help for this particular problem but it seems weird and misdirected.

Comment: I see, I wanted to show full text and be more specific since I am just a beginner

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to detect all square brackets and whatever is inside of them.

```
\[[^\[\]]+\]
```

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/uG3pO0/1) is a demo.

But you didn't specify which language you want to use.

Please note that this solution assumes that there is no interesting text inside of the square brackets, only quotations. But I think it is a reasonable assumption of Wikipedia.

Comment: If you find it useful please mark this answer with the green tick :-)